# Login failed exception on BizTalk Database when going via windows service, while it works via web api (within the same library)

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, biztalk

I'm getting a login failed exception on the BizTalk management database, while it has been proven that the ConnectionString works and the user has the rights (since I am using sa for testing). It works when going through Web Api, while it won't when going trough the windows service.

The exception I get looks like this:

> Cannot open database "BizTalkContextMgmtDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sa'. - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

I use the same connection string in the app config for the Windows Service as in the Web Config for the asp.net WebApi

The connection string I use looks like this:

```
    <add name="BizTalkContext" connectionString="Server=ServerName;Database=BizTalkMgmtDb;User ID=sa;Password=******;"   />
```

The code to connect is in the class library for communicating with BizTalk and the ConnectionString is set as follows:

```
    private static string Connectionstring = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BizTalkContext"].ConnectionString;
```

The strange thing here is when I try to run the method in this class library from within the web api, everyting works just fine! When I try to run the methods in the class library from within the Windows Service it throws the shown exception.

What could possibly be the problem here, since I use the same techniques and the same libray in both projects.

**EDIT**

*Rick van Bodegraven* suggested to add the following to  the connection string. "Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"

This resulted in a new exception:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Comment: Are you sure the Web API and the Windows Service are both using the same connection string in the configuration file ?.

Comment: Absolutely 100% sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that restarting my server and reinstalling the windows service somehow fixed the problem. I think I was doing everything right all along, there was just a bug in the deployment proces somewhere.

So I know this is not really an answer and the question is also not a known issue. People with the same problem can actually try to restart, re-install and re-deploy every single thing. That is unfortunately the only advice I have on this problem.